# Trying to get time in searched city but getting time in current location

Tags: android, kotlin

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:
search City-> pass timestamp from APi -> get current time in this city(such as Tokyo 17:00)
Right now I'm getting time in my current location.
Here is timestampConverter function:

```
fun timestampConverter(num: Long): String {
    var format = "HH:mm"
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(format)
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = num * 1000
    return formatter.format(calendar.time)
}
```

Also I've tried to get hour by converting string

```
fun time(string: String): String{
    val format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss+|-hh:mm"
    val expectedFormat = "hh:mm"
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(format)
    var date: Date? = null
    var convertedDate: String? = null
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(string)
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(expectedFormat)
        convertedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date)
        return convertedDate!!
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return ""
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-11-27T05:00:00-05:00"
        at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong pattern val `format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss+|-hh:mm"`, shouldn't include `+|-hh:mm`.
I was using format from http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm